# A user just voted to close five of my questions. Who should I contact?

Tags: support

A user just voted to close five of my questions.

Who should I contact to reverse the close votes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's probably unnecessary to contact anyone (at this time).

I'm not sure if there are voting scripts specifically related to close votes, but if they are, this may or may not trigger them.

More importantly though, it takes 5 votes to close a question, a close vote will place it in the close queue, but it still takes 4 more voters to close it.

If you do find a question you believe was closed in error (yours or someone else's), please flag it for reopening.

If this becomes a regular problem (though that seems hard to determine since close votes are anonymous until the question is closed), please send us a flag (on one of your posts or one of the offender's) for us to investigate more thoroughly.